# PageTransitionType animation doesn't work the first time

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, animation

When i open my app and go to an other page it doesn't do the animation. But when i click on the same page again it does the animation. How can i fix this?

problem

```
      return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 35,
        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        child: TextButton(
          child: const Text(
            "Wachtwoord vergeten?",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
          ),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(PageTransition(
              child: ResetPassword,
              type: PageTransitionType.fade)))
        );

    }
```

what it is now

```
  Widget forgetPassword(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 35,
        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        child: TextButton(
          child: const Text(
            "Wachtwoord vergeten?",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
          ),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(PageTransition(
              child: widget,
              type: PageTransitionType.fade)))
        );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GestureDetector(
                              onTap:
                                  () =>
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(PageTransition(
                                      child: SecondPage(),
                                      type: PageTransitionType.fade)),
```

try this.

Comment: How can i define widget to go to my Todoist page

Comment: it doesn't go to the page that i want anymore how can i fix this? i have changed the code to what it is now

Comment: you have to put second page in child

Comment: it still does not work on the first time